# Librosa MFCC feature extraction

Tags: mfcc

I wanna extract the mfcc futures with librosa library. anyone can explain to me what is the difference between librosa.feature.mfcc(y=audio, sr=sr, n_mfcc=40) and np.mean(librosa.feature.mfcc(y=audio, sr=sr, n_mfcc=40).T,axis=0) ???

Answer (score 0):

I think its each coefficient averaged over time.
So you will get an Output of 40 values

Answer (score 0):

np.mean() or numpy.mean() will **returns the average of the array elements**. So if you use np.mean() to your mfcc extraction, it will be return the average of it.

In np.mean(), **axis = 0 means along the column and axis = 1 means working along the row**. For example:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
np.mean(a) // 2.5
np.mean(a, axis=0) // array([2., 3.])
np.mean(a, axis=1) // array([1.5, 3.5])
```

Reference:

1. [numpy.mean() docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html)
2. [more about numpy.mean() - geeksforgeeks.org](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/numpy-mean-in-python)